# Send emails automatically in aspx c# sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to be able to send emails automatically (every week) to a person letting them know to add their hours in the system. I have a button that does the job of sending the emails but I would like to automatically send the emails.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Agent - You can use sp_send_dbmail to send email, and SQL Server Agent to schedule the job. All can be done within SQL Server. Can refer the below link for more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent

Or as you said you have a button already, so have a web logic already. You can use Hangfire package and schedule that function from your application. So you would be using the existing logic just few lines new to add job in HangFire.

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link about how to create a scheduled task to run a C# console application (as requested in comments above):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/

I have implemented this approach for multiple different purposes (including an implementation of an email class) and I would definitely recommend it.  it's very straightforward and easy to deploy from Visual Studio after the initial setup.